# Broken Requirements.txt?

Tags: python, django, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

To give all details about my issue it's probably best to give a slight backstory.
For the past few months I've been working on a Django project at work. Because of recent obvious events I'm working from home, thus I had to transfer the project to my home PC (using Git).

At work I made a requirements.txt, which I would use to get all the packages at home. This worked, but it wouldn't install at home, and I soon found out it was because the requirements.txt had a package that was invalid and didn't exist.
This is:
`pkg-resources==0.0.0`

I deleted it from the requirements file and everything went fine afterwards.

Fast forward to now: I'm trying to deploy the project on our amazon beanstalk, and its failing with this error:

```
2020-03-26 12:03:10    ERROR   Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
2020-03-26 12:03:13    ERROR   [Instance: i-0xxxxxxx] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2020-03-26 12:03:13    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-03-26 12:03:13    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-09xxxxxxxx'. Aborting the operation.
2020-03-26 12:03:13    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.

ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

So I did what was suggested, looked in the activity log and see:

```
  Collecting pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 34))
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 34)) (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 34))
  You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2020-03-26 11:40:21,832 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Which contains:

```
No matching distribution found for pkg-resources==0.0.0
```

I don't understand why its looking for an invalid package that I deleted from the requirements file some time ago. I've tried making a completely new requirements file and deploying, I've tried deploying without a requirements file, I've tried making changes to it, pushing it to Git and then deploying it, all without any success.

It also says line 34, while my requirements file is actually 33 lines.

Comment: empty lines in requirements.txt can cause parsing issues.

Comment: This is caused by a long fixed bug in pip in combinations with older Ubuntu versions. Solution: remove the line and update!

Comment: I've tried removing the empty closing line and that didn't help unfortunately, also the lnvalid line doesn't exist in my requirements file anymore so theres nothing to remove

Comment: Remove any `pkg-resources==0.0.0` if you have and update. Even your output is complaining about old versions.

Comment: I've upgraded pip, error stays the same. However there isnt a ```pkg-resources==0.0.0``` line anywhere, so I don't get it.

Comment: The error says your file */opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt* has a line 34 and that line is `pkg-resources==0.0.0`, no doubt about that! So you should investigate why the file you edited is not the same as the */opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt* file. Are you editing the correct file? Are you really pushing the correct git branch? Is Elastic Beanstalk using the correct branch?